# 3 or more consecutive entries in the last 15 days

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sequential

I have the following data:

```
ID       EMP_ID      SALE_DATE 
---------------------------------
1        777         5/28/2016
2        777         5/29/2016
3        777         5/30/2016
4        777         5/31/2016
5        888         5/26/2016
6        888         5/28/2016
7        888         5/29/2016
8        999         5/29/2016
9        999         5/30/2016
10       999         5/31/2016
```

i need to fetch data for emp_id having 3 or more days of consecutive sales in the last 15 days.
Output should be:
777
999

Following is the query:

```
SELECT TRUNC (sale_date), emp_id
                        FROM table1
                       WHERE sale_date >= SYSDATE - 14
                    GROUP BY TRUNC (sale_date), emp_id
            HAVING COUNT (*) >= 3
```

But this returns consecutive transactions in the last three days only.
Note: This is oracle.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: There are plenty of example on the internet. Look at this one, you can first organize them in consecutive dates group and then simply see which one has a EndDate-StartDate greater than 2, select a distinct, you may think about holidays and weekends too: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=133810

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one row per day, you can use `lead()`:

```
select distinct emp_id
from (select t1.*,
             lead(sale_date, 1) over (partition by emp_id order by sale_date) as sd_1,
             lead(sale_date, 2) over (partition by emp_id order by sale_date) as sd_2
      from table1 t1
      where sale_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 14
     ) t
where sd_1 = sale_date + 1 and
      sd_2 = sale_date + 2;
```

Comment: gives error "[Error] Execution (14: 50): ORA-30089: missing or invalid <datetime field>"

Comment: the above was a typo error. it should have been sd_1 = sale_date + interval '1' day in the last two lines. It works now. But is there a way to count (i.e. in this case 3) driven from another table?

Comment: @SudeepS, seems like you're using Oracle? Add the <oracle> tag to the question!

Comment: @SudeepS . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.